# Javascript window variable in Jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to optimize code but getting some errors. These execute correctly:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call( $('ZA1 .stat'), function( td ) {//ExcuteCode}
Array.prototype.forEach.call( $('ZA2 .stat'), function( td ) {//ExcuteCode}
Array.prototype.forEach.call( $('ZA19 .stat'), function( td ) {//ExcuteCode}
Array.prototype.forEach.call( $('ZA20 .stat'), function( td ) {//ExcuteCode}
```

Tried to condense to this but getting errors:

```
for (var trType in allTr) {
    //console.log(trType);
    Array.prototype.forEach.call( $( window[trType]+' .stat'), function( td ) {
    //Excute Code
    }
```

In console, I get the following error:

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object] .stat

Can I use window[] in a jquery selector?

Comment: What's `window[trType]`?

Comment: does $('ZA2 .stat') work in jquery? Shouldn't ZA2 be a proper selector?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just combine all your selectors:

```
$('ZA1 .stat, ZA2 .stat, ZA3 .stat').each(function(i, td) {
    // do stuff
});
```

If you want to optimize this code, you may as well use `.querySelectorAll()` instead of using half jQuery / half JavaScript.

Comment: trType doesn't reference a <tr> rather more variables (ZA1, ZA2, ZA3...).

Comment: @Mark I know `trType` is a property of some sorts; okay, so what's inside `window[trType]` then? What's `ZA1`, `ZA2`, etc.?

Comment: Does $('randomString .someClass') work in jquery? Shouldn't randomString be a proper selector?

Comment: @Huangism The OP starts off saying $('ZA2 .stat') is working, so I don't judge :)

Comment: but what does that do? does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is saying that there is a javascript object in the `window[trType]` variable, and when it is running `window[trType] + ' .stat'` it doesn't know what to do as there is no Object + string operator defined.

Try using `window[trType].find()`. The jQuery `.find()` method works identically to `$()` when using a context. So `window[trType].find(".stat");` will find all of the elements with the stat class that are children of the object in `window[trType]`.

You could also replace `Array.prototype.forEach.call(` with `$.each(`

And if your going to do that you could use:

```
window[trType].find('.stat').each(function(td){
```